# Is there a map function that also applies a context?

Tags: scala

Is there a `map` like function in Scala that renders: `M[A] -> M[B]` but also allows you to specify some context info kinda like in `scanLeft`? For instance, something like:

```
def mapWithContext(context: C, f: (C, A) => (C, B)): M[B]
```

`f` would be passed 1) the context info of type `C` 2) the current element in the list of type `A`
and it would then returns 1) the updated context info `C` 2) the transformed list element of type `B`. However, unlike `scanLeft` it would then discard the context info from the collection it is building and only return the `B`'s

Comment: What would be the advantage of this over `.map(a => f(c, b)._2)`?

Comment: No there isn't and shouldn't be one. `map` means apply a transformation preserving structure, it doesn't have the notion of order, technically speaking a valid implementation for map would apply the function to all the values in parallel. However, you may implement `map` in terms of `foldLeft` thus, you may implement that function in term of `scanLeft`.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez perhaps I should rephrase with `scanLeft` instead of `map` to make my point clearer. Good point about the parallelism, makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly, but the new (Scala 2.13) `unfold()` method comes close. It's available on almost all collection types, mutable and immutable. Here's the profile for `List`.

```
def unfold(init: S)(f: (S) => Option[(A, S)]): List[A]
```

It takes an initial state and continually applies `f()` until it returns `None`.

So what you could to is make the initial state a tuple `(S, M[A])` and make the `f()` function `f:(S,M[A]) => Option[(B, (S,M[A]))]`. The `f()` code would peal off the head of `M[A]` to produce each `B` element until `M[A]` is empty, when `f()` returns `None`.

Comment: Good idea!  Thanks for that.